# Web app not working on Samsung remote testing lab

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, remote-debugging

Here is my very simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="click">Click Me!</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#click").click(function() {
        alert("Clicked!");
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I created an android webapp with it. I tested it on my phone running 2.3.6 and it works as expected. When I test the same app on Samsung remote testing lab with any 4.1.1 or 4.1.2 device the alert does not get displayed. The app does work on a 4.0.3 device in the lab. I tried out a few other things , looks like no click handler is working. Any clues? 
I referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151372/touch-in-samsung-remote-test-lab-devices, but the poster has not provided his solution.

Edit: Initially I was using cordova-2.6.0.js. I thought maybe cordova has some problem on Android 4.1.1. But even after removing all references to cordova the problem persists.

Comment: Why the down votes? I have done my homework, I have asked a specific question, the topic is of interest to several people who might be wondering how to test their apps without purchasing every device out there. What have I done wrong ? Could some one please explain?

Comment: May be since its a "tool" kinda question. But lets wait for others who have downvoted to comment.

Comment: Did you test the page in the system browser without phone gap/cordova? Same error? Did you try debugging with wein.re for instance?

Comment: @mr.VVoo, no I did not try in the system browser. Will try it. What is wein.re?

Comment: @everydayweb.in With [wein.re](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) you can do remote debugging within phone (or mobile browsers in general). Very helpful for debugging webpages in phonegap.

Comment: @mr.VVoo, nah the click handlers do not work in system browser either. Something seriously wrong there.